# Cannot get my checkbox value to flow to a spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I know that Ui Service was deprecated in December but my functions should still work.  However, I feel like basic scripting no longer works for me.  I am trying to record the value of a checkbox to a spreadsheet so I'm using the method e.parameter.checkbox1 but my script cannot find the value. see below: When I try to pass the value of the checkbox into my spreadsheet, it gives me a "FALSE" return all the time and I don't know why. Any help?

```
function doGet(e){
var app = UiApp.createApplication();
var grid = app.createGrid(40,5).setId('grid');
var gridCart = app.createGrid(35,2).setId('gridCart');
var flyerOptionsGrid = app.createGrid(4,15).setId('flyerOptionsGrid').setStyleAttribute("border","2px solid #C0C0C0");
var panel = app.createHorizontalPanel();

var checkbox1 = app.createCheckBox("checkbox1").setId('checkbox1').setStyleAttribute('fontSize','10');
grid.setWidget(5, 1, checkbox1);

var addToCart = app.createButton('Add to Cart').setId('addToCart');
var addToCartButtonHandler = app.createServerClickHandler('addToCartButtonHandler');
addToCartButtonHandler.addCallbackElement(grid);
addToCart.addClickHandler(addToCartButtonHandler);
grid.setWidget(10, 1, addToCart);


panel.add(grid)
panel.add(gridCart)
app.add(panel)
return app;
}


function addToCartButtonHandler (e) {
var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()  
var savedCartSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1XRrJDHkHT0Rx7DROU0LESuRfCOZoErgJU40UjaKZ7Do');
var userCart = savedCartSS.getSheetByName(user)
var lastRow = userCart.getLastRow()

if (e.parameter.checkbox1 == 'true') {userCart.getRange(lastRow+1, 5, 1, 1).setValue("TRUE")} else {userCart.getRange(lastRow+1, 5, 1, 1).setValue("FALSE")}
return app;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert to HTML Service, this duplicates your code.  It successfully gets the value of the check box.

### Code.gs

```
function doGet() {

  var buyForm = HtmlService
    .createTemplateFromFile('purchase')
    .evaluate()
    .setTitle('Buy Stuff')
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);

  return buyForm;
};

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
};

function InsertInSS(argChkBox) {
  Logger.log('argChkBox: ' + argChkBox);
  var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()  
  var savedCartSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById('spreadsheet ID');
  var userCart = savedCartSS.getSheetByName(user)
  var lastRow = userCart.getLastRow()

  if (argChkBox === true) {
    Logger.log('Was on');
    userCart.getRange(lastRow+1, 5, 1, 1).setValue("TRUE");
    return true;
  } else {
    userCart.getRange(lastRow+1, 5, 1, 1).setValue("FALSE");
    return false;
  };
};
```

### purchase.html

```
<div>
  <input type='checkbox' id='idChkBox1'>
  <input type='button' value='add to cart' onmouseup='runGoogleScript()'>
</div>

<?!= include('SCRIPT_addToCart'); ?>
```

### SCRIPT_addToCart.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function onSuccess(argReturnValue) {
    alert('was successful ' + argReturnValue);
  };

  function runGoogleScript() {
    console.log('runGoogleScript ran!');

    var chkBoxValue = document.getElementById('idChkBox1').checked;

    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)
      .InsertInSS(chkBoxValue);
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you!  So is there something wrong with my original code?  I am trying to limp through the next week on Ui Service and then I will try to learn HTML Service but I would still like to use my original code.  Can you tell me why my code doesn't work?  Does this have anything to do Ui Service not being supported anymore by Google?

Comment: Sorry, not sure.  I did copy your code and try to run it myself, but had no luck.  No data was being passed into the event argument.  I looped through `e.parameter` and everything was `undefined`.